# How to insert option at specified index of select(Multiple) in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I insert an option element at a specified index in a `<select multiple>` element?

Thanks

Comment: Why voting down guys? This was once my problem.

Comment: why was this marked down?  When you mark down something, that little tooltip does suggest you leave a comment telling why you marked down... I mark down these markdowns.

Comment: He could spend more than 10 seconds formulating a question. Saying what he's tried, including some more content. Writing in structured English would be nice.

Answer (score 25):

```
$("select option").eq(index).before($("<option></option>").val(val).html(text));
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you give an example. I dint get what is index val and all.

Comment: This is either genius or a crazy hack.

Answer (score 15):

**Vanilla javascript (no jQuery) and cross browser.**

To insert a new option into the select "mySelect", with value of "1" and text of "text", before the 0th existing item:

`mySelect.options.add(new Option("text", "1"), mySelect.options[0]);`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#add%28%29

Answer (score 4):

And yet another option, sans jquery:

Markup:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="mySelect">
    <option>First</option>
    <option>Third</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDdl = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var myOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
    myOption.innerText = "Second";

    myDdl.options.insertBefore(myOption, myDdl.options[myDdl.options.length - 1]);

</script>
```

Comment: hi @Dipak - did you get any particular error/breakage that I can assist with?

Comment: use myDdl.options.add(myOption, index)

Answer (score 3):

I submit this answer because jquery was not specified in the question.

```
function insertOptionToSelect(select, idx, option) {
    var saved = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        saved.push(select.options[i]);
    }
    select.options.length = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = saved[i];
    }
    select.options[select.options.length] = option;
    while (i < saved.length) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = saved[i++];
    }
}
```

The following will insert an option at the selected index of select with id 'MyPizzaSelect':

```
var myselect = document.getElementById('MyPizzaSelect');
insertOptionToSelect(myselect, myselect.selectedIndex, new Option('Pizza Margarita', '12345'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you can do it:

```
var myOption = "<option>Dynamic Option</option>";
var index = 2;
$(myOption).insertBefore("select option:nth-child("+index+")");
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/T8n7f/8/)

Comment: I want to use elememts Id instead of using "select"

Comment: Because i have multiple elements

Comment: @Dipak That kind of modification is easy :) see here: http://jsfiddle.net/T8n7f/16/

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Replace **ELEMENT_NAME** with the id of your Single/Multi Select and **INDEX_VALUE** with the specified index, and **VALUE** with your string data.

**Syntax:**

```
document.getElementById("ELEMENT_NAME").options[INDEX_VALUE].innerHTML = "VALUE";
```

**Example:**

```
document.getElementById("MyOption").options[0].innerHTML = "HTMLisNotAProgrammingL";
```