# how to append option value in a specific index in jquery

Tags: jquery

I tried to append an option value in a particular position/index using jquery.

This is my code :

```
 function refreshDropDown(target,option){
var arrDatabases = getDatabases();  
var numOfDatabases = arrDatabases.length;
var hasPe= jQuery.inArray("pe",arrDatabases) >=0 ;
var onlyPe= (jQuery.inArray("pe",arrDatabases) >=0 && numOfDatabases == 1);

        if( !hasPe && !onlyPe && numOfDatabases !=0){
            jQuery(".lookForSelector             option[value='Publishers']").remove();

**jQuery(target).append(jQuery('<option>     </option>').val('Publishers').html('Publisher'));**

}
}
```

In this above code i want to append the value "publishers" with caption "publisher" at      19th position. Now it is getting appended in the last index. the value for the variable   target is ".lookForSelector".

Appreciate your timely help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912831/how-to-insert-option-at-specified-index-of-selectmultiple-in-html  please search little bit

Answer (score 4):

If you know the target you're appending to:

```
$(target + ' :nth-child(19)').after("<option value='publishers'>publishers</option>");
```

Here's a fiddle appending to the middle of a select: http://jsfiddle.net/E3wpg/

Comment: Thanks TymeJV for your reply. but my problem is how to append it in a particular index in a option value. for ex: i want to append publishers at 19th position in option values.

Comment: @anu I've updated my answer, can you try it out now and let me know how it goes?