# How to remove an item from a DropDownList basing on the item selected in another DropDownList in ASP MVC and using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have two dropdownlist which loads same values from a table in the base.

I want create an event that delete the item selected in the DropDwonList 1 from the DropDownList 2.

This is the code :

```
<%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "poste" })%>

<%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.NextPS, new { @id = "dd" })%>
```

So basing on the code above, when the item is selected in 'Poste',,,its similair should be deleted from 'Poste Suivant'.

This is what I try but it's  not worked :

```
function test3() {
    var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
    var posteElement = document.getElementById('poste');
    var currentIndexP = posteElement.selectedIndex;
    var currentIndexD = dd.selectedIndex;
    if (currentIndexP == currentIndexD) dd.removeChild(dd[currentIndex]);

}
```

I think the problem is : because I didn't define 'test3()' in the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the `onchange` attribute like you have done with the `id` attribute in your HTML helper:

```
<%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "poste", onchange = "test3()" })%>

<%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.NextPS, new { @id = "dd" })%>
```

Add an `onload` attribute to the body tag so that the function runs to remove the default selected item:

```
<body onload="test3()">
```

Then if we modify the javascript so that it removes the item from the second list based on value instead of index and add some code to store the lost option to add back in, everything should work nicely:

```
var removedOption = null;
var removedOptionIndex = -1;

function test3() {
    var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
    var posteElement = document.getElementById('poste');
    var currentValue = posteElement.options[posteElement.selectedIndex].value; // this will be the value of the selected option, '2' in this case: <option value="2">Two</option>
    var currentText = posteElement.options[posteElement.selectedIndex].text; // this will be the text of the selected option, 'Two' in this case: <option value="2">Two</option>

    // add the previously removed option back into the list in its previous position
    if (removedOption != null) {
        var newOpt = document.createElement("option");
        newOpt.value = removedOption.value;
        newOpt.innerHTML = removedOption.text;
        if (removedOptionIndex < 0) removedOptionIndex = 0;
        if (removedOptionIndex > dd.options.length) removedOptionIndex = dd.options.length;
        insertOptionToSelect(dd, removedOptionIndex, newOpt);
        removedOption = null;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) // loop through all of dd's options
    {
        if (dd.options[i].value == currentValue) // use this if you want to compare by value
        {
            removedOption = dd.options[i];
            removedOptionIndex = i;
            dd.removeChild(dd.options[i]);
            break;
        }
        if (dd.options[i].text == currentText) // use this if you want to compare by text
        {
            removedOption = dd.options[i];
            removedOptionIndex = i;
            dd.removeChild(dd.options[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function insertOptionToSelect(select, idx, option) {
    var saved = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        saved.push(select.options[i]);
    }
    select.options.length = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = saved[i];
    }
    select.options[select.options.length] = option;
    while (i < saved.length) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = saved[i++];
    }
}
```

Credit to pizzamonster for his answer to this question [How to insert option at specified index of select(Multiple) in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912831/how-to-insert-option-at-specified-index-of-selectmultiple-in-html) and his `insertOptionToSelect` function.

To compare by value or text just use the appropriate `if` statement and feel free to remove the other variable for tidiness. I gave you both options as I'm new to MVC myself and I'm not 100% sure about the rendered HTML =]

Comment: I've edited my answer, try that. Although one thing that does stand out is that if your user goes and selects every item in `poste`, there will be no options left in `dd`. Perhaps this should be run once only? Or maybe you need to add something else in to re-add the missing fields when the selected item is changed in `poste`?

Comment: Thx again for your work and sorry for the late, I tried your code and I didn't get any result :(( the item still exist !
About your remark, yes it should be deleted one time only,,,it means when I choose P1 for example in poste,,,it should be deleted temporary from dd,,,then i choose P2 in poste,,,dd must contain P1 but not P2,,,I hope that you understand me :) I wait your comment , Thx :))

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? Can you debug and step through the code and see where it's going wrong?

Comment: No,,,there is no error.
And I can't put a Breakpoint in the view :(((

Comment: You should be able to use your browser's developer tools to debug javascript code.

Comment: Ok there was a syntax error in my code, I've updated the answer to reflect. This code successfully removes the item from the `select` element.

Comment: Thx Sean,,,This is Works successfully, I will put it as answer to thank you for all that work ,,,but it still a little problem, the item are delteted once and for all. That's means didn't back when i change item. Is that any solution for that ?

Comment: Yep, I've added that to the answer as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30840/discussion-between-anouar-and-sean)